# How to add jQuery Datepicker option which accepts a function as an argument

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have added a date_popup field to a form :

```
$form['arrival_date'] = [
  '#type'                => 'date_popup',
  '#title'               => t('Arrival date'),
  '#date_format'         => 'd/m/Y',
  '#date_year_range'     => '0:+1',
  '#date_label_position' => 'none',
  '#default_value'       => '',
  '#size'                => '10',
];
```

I want to add an option to run a function using the onClose option so my js is :

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.ios2 = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('#edit-arrival-date-datepicker-popup-1').datepicker('option', {
        onClose: function (date) {
          // date will have the new date or empty string if no date
          // has been selected.
          alert(date);
          // Do something
        }
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

However the onClose event never executes.  If I remove the 'option' argument thus :

```
$('#edit-arrival-date-datepicker-popup-1').datepicker({
```

it does work, but my suspicion is that it is replacing the datepicker with a new one, rather than altering the existing options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ommit the 'option' parameter, the following modified version of your code worked for me:

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.ios2 = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('#edit-arrival-date-datepicker-popup-1').datepicker({
        onClose: function (date) {
          // date will have the new date or empty string if no date
          // has been selected.
          alert(date);
          // Do something
        }
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Stefanos,  thanks but I think what you are doing there appears to work, but in reality you are creating a new datepicker so any options you have set within the Drupal form definition will be lost.

Comment: Hey @elb, why do you think this is creating a new datepicker? The datepicker function should work both as a constructor, as well as a setter. In the case of the modified version of your code in my answer, it should work as a setter, if the selected element already has a datepicker object attached to it. Thanks for some thoughts or more details on this!

Comment: Stefanos, my experience was that when I omitted the 'option' parameter then I lost any of the options that I had set in my form_alter() such as the date format.  I presumed it was instantiating a new datepicker, but this is just a suposition.  Using the method I referenced ( but the SE Police have subsequently deleted, aaaargh !! ) avoided this.